# Supply exist argument COQ

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgfCW.png)

Hey guys.
So I have H0, I got my x and H1.
as far as I understand, if ill show that there is an x for which P x -> False, ill get a False and can discriminate the case.
I just dont understand how to provide that x and H1. I tried rewrite, apply and im just stuck.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Coq ! Could you provide a minimal working example with code insert rather than an image ? It helps helping you out in your proof :)
You might be looking for the `exfalso` (turns your goal into `False`) and `exists` tactics.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ As requested by @cbl please take a moment to translate the text in your image into a code block within your post _ Please take a moment to visit SO Help Center's 'Asking' section and specifically this link >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by cbl, you first use `exfalso` to turn your goal into False. Then you `apply H0` which leaves you with `exists x0 : X, P x0 -> False`. Then you use `exists x` which leaves you with H1, so that you can solve the goal with `exact H1`.

Comment: Thanks, I did what you and cbl suggested, it solved my problem. there is no way to supply the exists x0 and P x0 -> False into H1 directly without using exfalso?

Comment: Well yes, you can do `specialize (H0 (ex_intro _ _ H1)).` This will turn H0 into False. It helps to turn off notations in your IDE to see what the exists really is - it becomes obvious then.